# What's the purpose of "until" here?

Tags: meaning

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)*, Lupin says to Harry Potter:

> Lupin: Somebody did betray your parents...somebody who, **until** quite
> recently, I believed to be dead!

What's the purpose of "until" here?

Comment: Have you looked up "until" in a dictionary?

Comment: He's saying that he recently learned that the man was alive. Until then, he thought he was dead.?

Comment: Yep, you got it!

Comment: If we place ourselves in an ELL’s position (within some range of competence), it seems that the expectation to perform a step of basic research should be more reasonable in some cases compared to others. *Until’s* set of dictionary definitions are many and complex. The example text departs from the more simple and canonical in multiple ways and instances (did + v), (wh- word that might look like a relative clause), (pp which can prompt vague wonderings about passive constructions), all of which could predictably lead a perfectly reasonable 1/

Comment: and industrious learner to reason that asking here is the best course. TypeIA kindly asked her question above, and it looks like the OP did so and got what they needed from that while I was crafting my answer. Still, the OP selected my answer, at least hinting that it may have been useful. 2/

Comment: Further, consider that TypeIA answered this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/281795/how-to-call-residents-in-a-country-state-city-etc-is-there-any-rule-regardin/281797#281797 I found that googling the entire question led straight to an answer. By what principle does this merit closing while that doesn’t? I’m not whining. Of course there will be gray areas, and subjectivity. But I do give some consideration before answering and sometimes feel that some of us are a bit overzealous with the policing/tidying function. How much harm can we assume will result from this being open?

Comment: Btw. I know that at least some of the close voters have reasons and do a lot to improve the site. I’m only sharing my take. I also probably won’t get involved in detailed meta discussions or do more to support the moderators. But I would do my best to contribute from time-to-time, if this occurs a bit less often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s re-arrange and rephrase the excerpt a bit:

> I think somebody betrayed your trust. I think I know who it was that betrayed your trust. I think it was someone I thought was dead. But recently I found out that they are not dead. I thought they were dead until three days ago. Three days ago I discovered that they are still alive.

So in the “Harry Potter” text, *until* means *the recent ending of something that was true in the past.*

Here is another example:

> I was afraid of monsters until I was about nine or ten years old.

That means I was afraid beginning when I was younger and ending when I was nine or ten.

And another:

> John: Hello Bobby. What a surprise to meet you here. What are you doing?

> Bobby: I am buying an umbrella.

> John: Why? It’s not raining now.

> Bobby: Really? It was raining when I arrived here at the shopping mall. Look. My clothes are still wet!

> John: Right. It was raining until just five minutes ago.

And now an example closer to the original:

> Betty and John were playing a game to pass the time while waiting for dinner. Betty said, “I am thinking about someone who we both know. Guess who it is.”

> John said “Hmm...  Can you give me a clue?”

> ”Ok. It’s someone who’s in college.”

> ”Oh. I don’t have patience! Who is it?”

> ”It’s Michelle.”

> ”What? Michelle’s not in college! She just graduated.”

> ”Oh! I thought she was still in college.”

> ”I did too, until quite recently. I saw her a few days ago and she told me she graduated.”